# Passing a list from angular to c# through http request

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, asp.net-core

My method in c# receives a list as a parameter, I am trying to call this method in angular by passing it an array, but the problem is that the info doesn't reach the c# method, the list is always empty, even though there was information in the angular array.

```js
export class StationAllocationPostModel{

    idAppDeviceOwnerEntity: number;
    idAppDeviceOwnerEntityOriginal: number;
    idAppDeviceOwnerEntityRentalLocationId: number;
    Observations: string;
    selectedAppDevices: StationAllocationModel[];
}
```

```js
createNewStationAllocation(selectedAppDevices: StationAllocationPostModel){

    return this.post("home/CreateAppDeviceRentalLocationAllocation", selectedAppDevices, {
      params: {
        'idAppDeviceOwnerEntity': selectedAppDevices.idAppDeviceOwnerEntity,
        'idAppDeviceOwnerEntityRentalLocationId': selectedAppDevices.idAppDeviceOwnerEntityRentalLocationId,
        'Observations': selectedAppDevices.Observations,
        'selectedAppDevices': selectedAppDevices.selectedAppDevices
      }
    });
  }

public post(url: string, data: any, options = null) {

        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {

            let response;
            this.http.post(
                this.baseUrl + url,
                {
                    data: data
                },
                {
                    headers: options ? options.headers : null,
                    observe: options ? options.observe : null,
                    params: options ? options.params : null,
                    reportProgress: options ? options.reportProgress : null,
                    responseType: options ? options.responseType : null,
                    withCredentials: options ? options.withCredentials : null
                }
            )
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    response = data;
                    if (response && !response.success) {

                        if (response.response.ServerResponse[0].MessageType == "NOSESSIONEXCEPTION") {

                            localStorage.removeItem('userSession');
                            this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: this.router.url } });
                        }
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    resolve(null);
                    this.handleError(url, options ? options.params : null );
                    console.log(error);
                }, () => {
                        if (response) {
                            resolve(response);
                    } else {
                        resolve(null);
                    }
                }
            );
        })
    }
```

This is my c# method:

```cs
public Object CreateAppDeviceRentalLocationAllocation(<other params>, List<AppDeviceRentalLocationAllocationHistoryExtended> selectedAppDevices)
        {
...
        }
```

I am expecting that the c# method receives a list with elements, but it always comes out empty for some reason. The 'other params' are getting the right information, so I don't know what's wrong with the list.

Sorry for the long post, I'm new here.

Comment: The _what_ are getting the right information?

Comment: the other params*, sorry

Comment: C# is a language. Are you using .NET Core ASP or ASP.Net or any library to handle the requests?

Comment: it is ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 1):

Could you please form a param object on the C# method that holds the following :

```
public class SelectedAppDevice
{
    public int idAppDevice { get; set; }
    public int idAppDeviceOwnerEntity { get; set; }
    public int idAppDeviceOwnerEntityRentalLocationId { get; set; }
    public string Observations { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string EntityRentalLocationName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
    public int RentalStatus { get; set; }
    public int idAppDeviceRental { get; set; }
    public bool IsRentalStart { get; set; }
    public bool IsRentalEnd { get; set; }
    public object idNextExpectedEntityRentalLocationName { get; set; }
    public object NextExpectedEntityRentalLocationName { get; set; }
    public string LastKnownEntityRentingId { get; set; }
    public string CallerId { get; set; }
    public int RentalStatusId { get; set; }
    public int DeviceStatusId { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Observations { get; set; }
    public int idAppDeviceOwnerEntityRentalLocationId { get; set; }
    public int idAppDeviceOwnerEntity { get; set; }
    public List<SelectedAppDevice> selectedAppDevices { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

and make it as a controller method parameter :

```
public Object CreateAppDeviceRentalLocationAllocation(RootObject param)
        {
...
        }
```

Comment: could you please install fiddler and send me the request body sent to  the server ?

Comment: i have updated the answer upon your sent json 
i have used http://json2csharp.com/ to convert your JSON into C# classes , please try the new object structure submitted on the answer.
and make sure that the content type sent is 'application/json'